# Scaning ibeacon in Xamarin.android when app is killed is not working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am creating the Xamarin.android application with which I can scan the BLE device and notify the user when in range irrespective of the app is in the foreground, on pause or terminated. I am using ESP32 BLE device as a ibeacon. 
I have used  **AltBeacon library** and followed all the steps mentioned in the link below

https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

I have converted code for Xamarin.android.
I get a notification when the app is in the foreground and on pause state, but not when killed .

I have also tried using **Googles Nearby Message API**. But I am not able to detect ibeacon.

Here is code for the application class

```
[Application]
public class Myapplication : Application, IBootstrapNotifier
{
    BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSave;
    RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;

    public Myapplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership ownerShip) : base(handle, ownerShip)
    {
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.GetInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.BeaconParsers.Add(new BeaconParser().SetBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));

        backgroundPowerSave = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, Helper.GetRegion());
    }

    public void DidDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region)
    {
        Helper.ShowNotification(this, "Beacon - state for region", "Log in");
    }

    public void DidEnterRegion(Region region)
    {
        regionBootstrap.Disable();
       //show notification 
    }

    public void DidExitRegion(Region region)
    {
       //show notification 
    }
}
```

How to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Testing detection after "killing" an app is tricky, and whether or not it works (usually it does) depends on exactly how you kill it and what device manufacturer you are talking about.

Read all the details on [this page](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/resume-after-terminate.html) carefully to make sure you are testing a scenario that is expected to work.